# iOS 10 Siri support for Workouts with custom vocabulary

Tags: ios, ios10, siri, sirikit, intents-extension

In my app I'd like to be able to tell Siri something like:

So I enabled the Siri capability, added a target, implemented the `INStartWorkoutIntentHandling` (and also the other) delegate methods and everything works.

I can now say `Start a workout with MyAppName`. Perfekt!

Now I'd like to tell her something like `Start an activity using MyAppName`, or even `Start a hike using MyAppName`.

So I went and added a `AppIntentVocabulary.plist` looking something like that:
[image]
Quick question there... the Vocabulary item identifier... If the work- Hike f.e. should be used for start, end, pause, resume, cancel... should the identifier be the same for all of them?

Now I face three problems.

**1.** I can tell Siri `Start a hike` and it will work, she will ask me which app I should be using. I tell her `Start a hike using MyApp` and she will tell me that she can't find that on Apple Music?!? What the hell?

**2.** If I add the word `Activity` into my Vocabulary she will only open the iOS Activities App... Never ask if I may want to open my app.

**3.** On submission I get a punch of missing words-warnings
Like `No example phrase was provided for INStartWorkoutIntent in the "en" language` which I do have! or `Sample phrase "Start a Hike using MyAppName" was not classified as a INStartWorkoutIntent intent`

I would be very very happy if someone could show me a valid sample of a `AppIntentVocabulary.plist` file that works fine with siri and iTunes Connect!

Comment: For #3, I opened a ticket with Apple Developer Technical Support and they said it was a bug and that I should file it.

Comment: So at least #3 is not really a bug on my side? And about #1 and #2 ... how did you write your `AppIntentVocabulary.plist`? And is Siri properly responding for you?

Comment: Siri is properly responding to me. But I am only using the AppIntentVocabulary.plist for Siri examples for INSendMessageIntent's so I'm afraid I won't be any help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no you cannot replace workout to activity or hike.

Sirikit only supports very limited doamins as of now.

In case of workout intent,Siri expects the phrase :Workout to be in the spoken phrase else siri will not open the app.

For exmaple:You will have to say Start a hike workout using My app.Before that you will have to register custom vocabulary and include hike or any other workout name in invocabulary list

Answer (score -1):

The solution is:

1. Launch the Settings app, then scroll down and tap on “Safari.” Under the “General” section at the top, tap on the “Search Engine” row.
2. Select a preferred search engine from the list. This will change Siri's  default search from apple music to your desired one.

I hope this works. Before trying this out please keep in mind that I am not responsible for any problems or loss while doing this procedure you are doing this at your own risk sir.

I will try my best to check on your second and third problems and reply to that soon.

Thank you

Comment: Hi Roshan, Thanks for your help. The problem with 1. is not that I want an other search engine. I want Siri to be smart enough to not search for music but to `start a hike` even if I add my apps name to the phrase. I am wondering if that's a problem with my vocabulary file or if Siri simple is stupid...